# Azure Functions Disappear in Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function app that should contain 5 Azure Functions, and I have configuration to run those from a package file.

The problem is that when I look in the Azure Portal, for some reason it only shows 1 of the functions (Timer function is there, but 4 HTTP functions are missing, I have HTTP 404 when I then try to call these HTTP functions from other places)
[image]

This is weird, because when I go to Function App Overview and download app content from there, then zip package shows all functions.

[image]

I tried restarting this function app and redeploying the package with NO effect at all, it still shows only one of those functions

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, does anybody have any ideas?

EDIT:
I have added 2nd timer function and uploaded the package, restarted function app just to make sure. After that when downloading app content it shows 6 azure functions in zip package (2 timer and 4 http) as expected. However in the portal it still shows just one timer function as previously. Is this some kind of caching issue?

Comment: Is there one solution / project with all the functions or are they places in seperated projects? And also, how do you deploy them?

Comment: All in one project, deployed with Azure Pipelines, generated artifact contains all functions. Then released with zip deploy - AzureFunctionAppV1 task.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I found that the reason was this configuration in host.json file added by another team member. After commenting it out, this started working fine.

[image]